# Make command prompt wait till all processes finish execution

Tags: batch-file, process, wait

I am running a batch file through java code. My batch file consists of several commands. i want this process to terminate only after the execution of all the processes.
my java code is

```
String command = "cmd /c start /wait C:\\python27\\tutorial\\check.bat "+key+" "+formattedDate;
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

There are some function after this which i want to execute after all the processes in my batch file are completed.
My batch file has

```
cd\
cd python27
cd tutorial
start scrapy crawl flipkart -a key="%1" -o %2flipkart.xml
start scrapy crawl myntra -a key="%1" -o %2myntra.xml
start scrapy crawl jabong -a key="%1" -o %2jabong.xml
start scrapy crawl hs18 -a key="%1" -o %2hs18.xml
start scrapy crawl indiatimes -a key="%1" -o %2indiatimes.xml
start scrapy crawl shopclues -a key="%1" -o %2shopclues.xml
start scrapy crawl croma -a key="%1" -o %2croma.xml
start scrapy crawl amazon -a key="%1" -o %2amazon.xml
exit
```

Due to this exit command the batch file is returning back and the main thread continues. I want this batch file to exit only after all the processes are completed. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you intend to set all the `scrapy` threads to launch asynchronously?  If not, simply remove the `start` from each line to accomplish your goal.

If the non-blocking threads were intentional, then I'm guessing the threads will probably complete after unpredictable durations, and `scrapy crawl amazon` might not necessarily be the last thread to finish.

You could add a loop to your batch script just above `exit` to check whether `scrapy` exists in the process list -- something like this:

```
cd \python27\tutorial
start scrapy crawl flipkart -a key="%1" -o %2flipkart.xml
start scrapy crawl myntra -a key="%1" -o %2myntra.xml
start scrapy crawl jabong -a key="%1" -o %2jabong.xml
start scrapy crawl hs18 -a key="%1" -o %2hs18.xml
start scrapy crawl indiatimes -a key="%1" -o %2indiatimes.xml
start scrapy crawl shopclues -a key="%1" -o %2shopclues.xml
start scrapy crawl croma -a key="%1" -o %2croma.xml
scrapy crawl amazon -a key="%1" -o %2amazon.xml

echo Waiting for other threads to complete...
:wait
>NUL 2>NUL (
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak || ping -n 2 localhost
    tasklist /fi "imagename eq scrapy.exe" | find /i "scrapy" && goto wait
)
exit
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I execute each command via cmd.exe so that I can redirect an unused file handle to a lock file. The process holds an exclusive lock on the file until it completes. The file cannot be deleted until the lock is released (the process ends)

I have a loop that attempts to delete the lock files. If a deletion fails, then the process must still be alive so it loops back to try again. I use TIMEOUT to introduce a delay so that the deletion loop does not swamp the CPU.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd \python27\tutorial

set "jobs=flipkart myntra jabong hs18 indiatimes shopclues croma amazon"

for %%A in (%jobs%) do start cmd /c scrapy crawl %%A -a key="%1" -o "%~2%%A.xml" 9^>%%A.lock

:waitForCompletion
timeout /t 1 nobreak >nul
for %%A in (%jobs%) do (
  del %%A.lock >nul 2>nul
  if exist %%A.lock goto :waitForCompletion
)

exit
```

There is probably no need to see any output in your console windows, so you could use START /B to run each process within the same console, and redirect stdout to nul to hide the output. I left stderr as is just in case an error pops up.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd \python27\tutorial

set "jobs=flipkart myntra jabong hs18 indiatimes shopclues croma amazon"

for %%A in (%jobs%) do start /b cmd /c scrapy crawl %%A -a key="%1" -o "%~2%%A.xml" ^>nul 9^>%%A.lock

:waitForCompletion
timeout /t 1 nobreak >nul
for %%A in (%jobs%) do (
  del %%A.lock >nul 2>nul
  if exist %%A.lock goto :waitForCompletion
)

exit
```